# How to use a While Loop when returning multiple Values using a variable?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, restore

I'm trying to return multiple values for my Log Backups, cause when I use a  Set variable it only returns one value. I thought about using a while loop as this will loop and return all my logs close to the restore point. However returns back NULL Value. When I use a Set Variable I'm getting the latest Transaction Log file back but I'm not getting the previous logs before that after the latest Full I think this is to do with me using a Set variable as this only outputs one value.

```
DECLARE @LogbackupFile nvarchar(max), 
@DatabaseName varchar(500) = 'ns_lots_of_vlfs', 
@DiffDate datetime = null, 
@LogDate datetime = null, 
@RestoreDate datetime = '2023-01-30 12:00:06.000', 
@FullBackupFile nvarchar(max), 
@FullBackupDate datetime 

SELECT 
  TOP 1 @FullBackupFile = bmf.physical_device_name, 
  @FullBackupDate = bs.backup_finish_date 
FROM 
  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id 
WHERE 
  bs.type = 'D' 
  AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName 
  AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
ORDER BY 
  backup_finish_date DESC IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable_log') IS NOT NULL 
DROP 
  TABLE #TempTable_log
SELECT 
  bmf.family_sequence_number, 
  bmf.media_family_id, 
  bmf.media_count, 
  bmf.logical_device_name, 
  bmf.physical_device_name, 
  bmf.device_type, 
  bmf.physical_block_size, 
  bmf.mirror, 
  bs.backup_set_id, 
  bs.backup_set_uuid, 
  bs.first_family_number, 
  bs.first_media_number, 
  bs.last_family_number, 
  bs.last_media_number, 
  bs.catalog_family_number, 
  bs.catalog_media_number, 
  bs.position, 
  bs.expiration_date, 
  bs.software_vendor_id, 
  bs.name, 
  bs.description, 
  bs.user_name, 
  bs.software_major_version, 
  bs.software_minor_version, 
  bs.software_build_version, 
  bs.time_zone, 
  bs.mtf_minor_version, 
  bs.first_lsn, 
  bs.last_lsn, 
  bs.checkpoint_lsn, 
  bs.database_backup_lsn, 
  bs.database_creation_date, 
  bs.backup_start_date, 
  bs.backup_finish_date, 
  bs.type, 
  bs.sort_order, 
  bs.code_page, 
  bs.compatibility_level, 
  bs.database_version, 
  bs.backup_size, 
  bs.database_name, 
  bs.server_name, 
  bs.machine_name, 
  bs.flags, 
  bs.unicode_locale, 
  bs.unicode_compare_style, 
  bs.collation_name, 
  bs.is_password_protected, 
  bs.recovery_model, 
  bs.has_bulk_logged_data, 
  bs.is_snapshot, 
  bs.is_readonly, 
  bs.is_single_user, 
  bs.has_backup_checksums, 
  bs.is_damaged, 
  bs.begins_log_chain, 
  bs.has_incomplete_metadata, 
  bs.is_force_offline, 
  bs.is_copy_only, 
  bs.first_recovery_fork_guid, 
  bs.last_recovery_fork_guid, 
  bs.fork_point_lsn, 
  bs.database_guid, 
  bs.family_guid, 
  bs.differential_base_lsn, 
  bs.differential_base_guid, 
  bs.compressed_backup_size, 
  bs.key_algorithm, 
  bs.encryptor_thumbprint, 
  bs.encryptor_type INTO #TempTable_log
FROM 
  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id 
WHERE 
  bs.database_name = @DatabaseName 
  AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
  AND bs.backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND bs.type = 'L' 
  AND bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%Log%' 
WHILE (@LogbackupFile IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN 
SELECT 
  @LogBackupFile = bmf.physical_device_name 
FROM 
  #TempTable_log bmf
WHERE 
  bmf.database_name = @DatabaseName 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND bmf.type = 'L' 
  AND bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%Log%' PRINT @LogBackupFile END 
SELECT 
  @LogbackupFile
```

Comment: Your `while` stops when @LogBackupFile is not null, and then you `select` that one value. One way if you want multiple results is to remove the `while` and just `select * from #TempTable_log`

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me what you're asking, but it sounds like the problem is you want to do this at the end:

```
SELECT  @LogbackupFile
```

Where `@LogbackupFile` was populated in a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  @LogBackupFile = bmf.physical_device_name 
FROM 
  #TempTable_log bmf
WHERE 
  bmf.database_name = @DatabaseName 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND bmf.type = 'L' 
  AND bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%Log%'
```

When what you should do is **just select the column** and not worry about trying to set a variable at all:

```
SELECT 
  bmf.physical_device_name As LogBackupFile
FROM 
  #TempTable_log bmf
WHERE 
  bmf.database_name = @DatabaseName 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
  AND bmf.backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
  AND bmf.type = 'L' 
  AND bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%Log%'
```

Now your client code can look at the entire result set.

Even better, looking through the code I'm extremely confident this entire thing could be re-written as a single SQL query, with no temp tables or variables at all other than the `@DatabaseName`, `@RestoreDate`, and `@Diffdate` inputs. However, there a few places where the desire to express the code in a procedural paradigm, rather than set-based, is clouding the intent. Also, it is probably easier to grab the `@FullBackupDate` value in a separate query.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(500) = 'ns_lots_of_vlfs', 
    @DiffDate datetime = null, 
    @RestoreDate datetime = '2023-01-30 12:00:06.000', 
    @FullBackupDate datetime 

SELECT TOP 1 @FullBackupDate = bs.backup_finish_date 
FROM  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id 
WHERE bs.type = 'D' 
    AND bs.database_name = @DatabaseName 
    AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
ORDER BY bs.backup_finish_date DESC 

SELECT bmf.physical_device_name As LogBackupFile 
FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bs.media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id 
WHERE bs.database_name = @DatabaseName 
    AND bs.backup_finish_date <= @RestoreDate 
    AND bs.backup_finish_date > ISNULL(@DiffDate, @FullBackupDate) 
    AND bs.type = 'L' 
    AND bmf.physical_device_name LIKE '%Log%'
```

And again: this should send the appropriate data back to the client. If you're having trouble retrieving this data perhaps try posting your client code.